# Returning sum of time by day using date_trunc using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql query that is returning time spent logged in for users

```
select sum(duration) as time_spent, date_trunc('day', date)::date as date
  from user_activities
  where name = 'session'
  and user_id = '#{user_id}'
  group by date
  order by 2
```

It's working mostly fine, but I found some edge cases where users were logged in on a given day for more than 24 hours. When I dug into this, I discovered that one user had the following start/end time in their sessions on a given day which summed to more than 24hrs:

```
[2023-04-24 00:00:54.457183 UTC, 2023-04-24 00:02:01.388673 UTC],                             
[2023-04-24 00:13:22.536908 UTC, 2023-04-24 18:38:02.108004 UTC],                             
[2023-04-24 23:35:56.81623 UTC, 2023-04-25 20:24:20.60667 UTC]
```

so they were logged in at midnight for two minutes, logged in again from midnight to 6pm the next day and then again at 11pm until 8pm the next day. the query is summing up all of those times (which in fact does make sense, that's what i'm asking it to do), but I'd like instead to sum up time from midnight to midnight so that this would make a duration of (approximately) 2 minutes (first session) + 1105 minutes (second session) + 25 minutes (last session, up to midnight of the given day).

The relevant columns of the `user_activities` table looks like this:

```
:name=>"session",                                                                                    
:user_id=>"xxx",                                                                                                               
:start_time=>2023-04-24 23:35:56.81623 UTC,                                                       
:end_time=>2023-04-25 20:24:20.60667 UTC,                                                         
:duration=>1,                                                                                      
:date=>#<Date: 2023-04-30 ((2460065j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
```

The research I've done makes me thing I can use `between` (such as [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-a-sql-query-for-a-specific-date-range-and-date-time/)) but i haven't found a way to make that work while using `date_trunc`. I'm sure there *is* a way, but I'm a novice sql user at best and this is really giving me trouble. Thanks for any help!

Comment: i think for postgres a view would be a good decision, splitting up overnights in 2 rows, start_time 23:00:00 to end_time 23:59:59 and for the next day start_time 00:00:00 to end_time 20:24:20, using a union all and some case when

Answer (score 1):

The query below shows sample data of your user adding an other user with a session over two days (to demonstrate the principle)

The subquery `day_cnt` calculates the minimal start date of the sessions and the `count_days` that is covered with the sessions.

This is used in subquery `cal` to generate a list of all dates in your data.

This list of the dates is used to make the *midnight split* in the join in `dt2`, where also the *corrected* start and end timestamps are calculated (suffixed with `2`)

Finally the `extract ( epoch` is used to get the duration in minutes of the splitted sessions.

**Query with Sample Data**

```
with dt as ( 
select * from (values
('xxx', '2023-04-24 00:00:54.457183 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2023-04-24 00:02:01.388673 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ),                             
('xxx', '2023-04-24 00:13:22.536908 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2023-04-24 18:38:02.108004 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ),                             
('xxx', '2023-04-24 23:35:56.81623 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2023-04-25 20:24:20.60667 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
('yyy', '2023-04-24 23:35:00.00000 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2023-04-26 20:00:00.00000 +02'::TIMESTAMPTZ)
) dt(user_id, start_time, end_time)
),
day_cnt as (
select min(start_time::date) start_date, (max(end_time::date) - min(start_time::date))+1 count_days from dt),
cal as (
select  start_date + generate_series( 1, count_days)-1 cal_date
from day_cnt),
dt2 as (
select dt.*, cal.cal_date,
greatest(dt.start_time,cal.cal_date::TIMESTAMPTZ) start_time2,
least(dt.end_time, (cal.cal_date+1)::TIMESTAMPTZ) end_time2
from dt
join cal on cal.cal_date between dt.start_time::date and dt.end_time::date
)
select dt2.*,
round(extract(epoch from (end_time2 - start_time2) )/60) duration
from dt2
```

**Output**

```
user_id|start_time                   |end_time                     |cal_date  |start_time2                  |end_time2                    |duration|
-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+
xxx    |2023-04-24 00:00:54.457183+02|2023-04-24 00:02:01.388673+02|2023-04-24|2023-04-24 00:00:54.457183+02|2023-04-24 00:02:01.388673+02|       1|
xxx    |2023-04-24 00:13:22.536908+02|2023-04-24 18:38:02.108004+02|2023-04-24|2023-04-24 00:13:22.536908+02|2023-04-24 18:38:02.108004+02|    1105|
xxx    | 2023-04-24 23:35:56.81623+02| 2023-04-25 20:24:20.60667+02|2023-04-24| 2023-04-24 23:35:56.81623+02|       2023-04-25 00:00:00+02|      24|
xxx    | 2023-04-24 23:35:56.81623+02| 2023-04-25 20:24:20.60667+02|2023-04-25|       2023-04-25 00:00:00+02| 2023-04-25 20:24:20.60667+02|    1224|
yyy    |       2023-04-24 23:35:00+02|       2023-04-26 20:00:00+02|2023-04-24|       2023-04-24 23:35:00+02|       2023-04-25 00:00:00+02|      25|
yyy    |       2023-04-24 23:35:00+02|       2023-04-26 20:00:00+02|2023-04-25|       2023-04-25 00:00:00+02|       2023-04-26 00:00:00+02|    1440|
yyy    |       2023-04-24 23:35:00+02|       2023-04-26 20:00:00+02|2023-04-26|       2023-04-26 00:00:00+02|       2023-04-26 20:00:00+02|    1200|
```

The actual *aggregation* is left out as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns the sum of the daily session times in seconds:

```
SELECT SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (  LEAST(ua.end_time, d.session_day + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
                               - GREATEST(ua.start_time, d.session_day)))) AS daily_time_seconds,
       d.session_day
  FROM user_activities ua
  CROSS JOIN generate_series(start_time::date, end_time::date, INTERVAL '1' DAY) d(session_day)
 WHERE name = 'session'
   AND user_id = '#{user_id}'
 GROUP BY d.session_day
 ORDER BY d.session_day;
```

This query depends on all timestamps being in the same time zone. If mixed time zones are used, then the query should be modified to translate each timestamp to a common time zone.

A few notes regarding issues in the original question:

1. Avoid using keywords or built-in function names as column identifiers (e.g., 'DATE').
2. Use names instead of ordinals in `GROUP` and `ORDER BY` clauses to improve readability and maintainability.
3. Use bound parameters instead of string interpolation to minimize the risk of SQL injection attacks.